# Easy way to return JSON in Camel HttpMessage from a Processor

Tags: apache-camel

I thought there was an easy way to tell Camel that it has to represent an object as a JSON when return to client.

The following should return a json array like `["test the west"]`, but somehow it doesn't. I know there should be some automatic conversion. If not, I know how to make a JSON form an array, but I am seeking for a least verbose and most automated approach to make it easier in the future.

```
private class Complete implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        HttpMessage http = exchange.getIn(HttpMessage.class);
        ArrayList<String> is = new ArrayList<>(4);
        is.add("test the west");
        //HttpMessage out = exchange.getOut(HttpMessage.class);
        http.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        http.setBody(is);
    }
}
```

I would even like to avoid setting the content type, relying on the incoming Accept headers... Any advice?

**UPD** this seems to automatically create json out of the List, but this looks unreliable and also doesn't respect Accept headers

```
http.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
http.setBody(is, String.class);
```

Comment: are you using camel rest dsl to listen to web requests? if you are then http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html look for the option RestBindingMode.Auto. This will do the marshalling and unmarshalling by itself.

Comment: thanks, in this example, no. Messages come from pure `jetty:` endpoint